# puzzle solving question

Tags: probability, logic, problem-solving

On a hot summer day,landon and mariah ate seven Popsicle. With the sticks left over,they challenged themselves to the following game:
each player alternates turns picking up one,two,or three consecutive sticks
The stick must be picked up in order from left to right
player one starts with the first stick on the left side
the player who picks up the last stick loses

Landon goes first and picks up exactly one stick. How many sticks must mari ah pick up to ensure that she wins?

my work

Since there are 7 sticks and landon picks exactly one stick ,mariah must pick up the 3 sticks to ensure that she wins

Comment: There are two wrong things with your answer: 1. The person picking up the last stick looses. 2. You can pick only 1,2, or 3 sticks, not 6.

Comment: yeah so mariah must pick 3 so she wins,meaning landon will loose

Comment: so the answer left with is 3

Comment: If she picks 3, there are 3 sticks left. Landon picks 2, so Mariah has to pick the last one and she looses.

Comment: so your saying she has to pick 2 in order to win

Comment: im a little confused

Comment: Try to repeat the above argument. If she picks two, there are 4 sticks left. Landon will pick 3. So Mariah looses again

Comment: ok,iM CONFUSED AND iM GETTING 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mariah needs to pick up one stick. There will be 5 left. If Landon picks up 1, Mariah will pick 3, so Landon looses. If Landon picks 2, Mariah will pick 2. If Landon picks 3, Mariah will get one.

Comment: OH OK ,so mariah only needs to pick up 1 in order win

Comment: thank you for your help,it makes sense now

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote or accept the answer, if you find it useful

Comment: yes,I have done  it just now @Andrei